# Sketch stops printing after writing a few times

Tags: progmem

I am trying to build a random horoscope printer. I have a series of strings in an array which I am storing in program memory. I then pick a random number and print that index concatenated with a title. But it often (but not always) only runs 4 or 5 times.

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

const char string_0[] PROGMEM = "You have a great need for other people to like and admire you. ";
const char string_1[] PROGMEM = "You have a tendency to be critical of yourself. ";
const char string_2[] PROGMEM = "You have a great deal of unused capacity which you have not turned to your advantage. ";
const char string_3[] PROGMEM = "While you have some personality weaknesses, you are generally able to compensate for them. ";
const char string_4[] PROGMEM = "Your sexual adjustment has presented problems for you. ";
const char string_5[] PROGMEM = "Disciplined and self-controlled outside, you tend to be worrisome and insecure inside. ";
const char string_6[] PROGMEM = "At times you have serious doubts as to whether you have made the right decision or done the right thing. ";
const char string_7[] PROGMEM = "You prefer a certain amount of change and variety and become dissatisfied when hemmed in by restrictions and limitations. ";
const char string_8[] PROGMEM =  "You pride yourself as an independent thinker and do not accept others' statements without satisfactory proof. ";
const char string_9[] PROGMEM = "You have found it unwise to be too frank in revealing yourself to others. ";
const char string_10[] PROGMEM = "At times you are extroverted, affable, sociable, while at other times you are introverted, wary, reserved. ";
const char string_11[] PROGMEM = "Some of your aspirations tend to be pretty unrealistic. ";
const char string_12[] PROGMEM = "Security is one of your major goals in life. ";

const char* const string_table[] PROGMEM = {string_0, string_1, string_2, string_3, string_4, string_5, string_6, string_7, string_8, string_9, string_10, string_11, string_12};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  randomSeed(analogRead(2));   
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println("WE GOING TO LOOP NOW");
    char buffer[50];
    int rand = random(0,12);
    Serial.println(rand);
    strcpy_P(buffer, (char*)pgm_read_word(&(string_table[rand]))); // Necessary casts and dereferencing, just copy.
    char text[15] = "Your horoscope";
    String output;
    output = strcat(text, buffer);
    Serial.println(output);
    delay(1000);
}
```

I also sometimes don't seem to get very clean results, but I'm not sure why. I.e. printing WWWW... and missing the first part of the string in the serial monitor.

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWE GWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWE GOING TO LOOP NOW
1
Your horoscopeYou have a tendency to be critical of yourself. 
WE GOING TO LOOP NOW
3
or them. While you have some personality weaknesses, you are generally able to compensate for them. 
WE GOING TO LOOP NOW
4
Your horoscopeYour sexual adjustment has presented problems for you. 
WE GOING TO LOOP NOW
2
ge. You have a great deal of unused capacity which you have not turned to your advantage.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is undefined behavior. You define your buffer to have a length of 50 bytes:

> char buffer[50];

This is too short for most of the strings you want copy into it and you will thus overwrite other variables.

The simplest solution is to increase the buffer size so that the longest string fits (e.g. 150). You will see that it then works as you expect. Take a look at http://linux.dd.com.au/wiki/Arduino_Static_Strings for hints how to avoid wasting RAM for the buffer.